# Connecting to Embedded Bluetooth Device From Android Device

Tags: android

i just started working on Connecting to Embedded BT Device through My Android Phone.It is connecting fine but i am facing problem when i am not disconnecting it properly. I mean first close socket and then any i/o steams opened.

But when i turn off my Bluetooth suddenly in device how will i know the bluetooth is get disconnecting. is there is any way to receive  Bluetooth disconnecting listener all the time in the APP.

Any Ideas ....?
Thanks

```
mmSocket= device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuidToTry);
try
{
    mmSocket.connect();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    mmSocket.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this-
Create a broadcast receiver in your code Like this:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                // BT is turened off.
            }
            else{
                // BT is turened on.
              }
        }
 }
};
```

and register that broadcastreceiver for following intent filter:

`IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);`